# C# why this snippet valid? Could anyone explain what are they and how to use?

Tags: c#

```
private bool duplicate;
public bool duplicateNumber
{
    get
    {
        return duplicate;
    }
    set
    {
        duplicate = value;
    }
}
```

What does this snippet mean?
How to use it? I am new on c# and know java only.
the variable `value` doesn't need to be declared seems...

Why don't just make a getter or setter for a private variable?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: From SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948816/getters-setters-and-properties-best-practices-java-vs-c-sharp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend reading on [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: What does the benefit ? i can make a getter or setter for a private variable..?

Comment: @KitHo The benefit is that you might have additional logic in you setter. If you only need the property you can use [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) in which case you don't need the private field at all

Comment: The link has a private field with a public property, that is the purpose.  You could also add logic, for example a `FullName` property could concatenate the values of the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to MSDN's Properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Quoting:

> Note that in a property Set method a special `value` variable is
>   available. This variable contains the value that the user specified,
>   for example:

```
myName = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

your duplicateNumber is property. When u assign it like

duplicateNumber = false;

it becomes like

```
set
{
      duplicate= false;
}
```

where value is the value passed to the property.

when u fetch that property like

```
bool xyz = duplicateNumber;
```

this is called

```
get
{
    return false;
}
```

where false is the value of duplicate variable.