# C# private variable & java private variable getter & setter - Difference?

Tags: c#, java, getter-setter

I am trying to understand the difference between the C# auto declaration of variables with getters & setters & the java declaration.

In java I usually do this:

```
private int test;

public int getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(int test) {
    this.test = test;
}
```

But in C# I tried something like this:

```
private int test { public get; public set};
```

But that did not allow access to the variable at all.
So I ended up with this:

```
public int test { get; set; }
```

So this way I could access the variable test from outside of the class.

My question is, what is the difference between these two? And is the C# implementation of making the variable public a bad idea?

In C# I have declared the variable as "public". Whereas in java it is declared as "private". Does this have any impact?

**Found a really good answer (in addition to those below) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948816/getters-setters-and-properties-best-practices-java-vs-c-sharp?rq=1)**

Comment: Your first snippet of C# code simply wouldn't have compiled at all - it's not a matter of not allowing access to the variable - it's simply invalid code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is exactly the same.

The automatic property you defined in C# will compile down to getter and setter methods anyway. They are classified as "syntactic sugar".

This:

```
public int Test { get; set; }
```

..is compiled to this:

```
private int <>k____BackingFieldWithRandomName;

public int get_Test() {
    return <>k____BackingFieldWithRandomName;
}

public void set_Test(int value) {
    <>k____BackingFieldWithRandomName = value;
}
```

Comment: But in C# I have declared the variable as "public". Whereas in java it is declared as private. Does this have any impact?

Comment: No. The compiler will create a private backing field for you. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you have a backing field.

In `C#` You can do:

```
private int test { get; set; };
```

Or make the `property` public (Perfectly valid)

```
public int test { get; set; };
```

You can also have backing fields in `C#`, these were more common before [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) were introduced in the language.

For instance:

```
private int _number = 0; 

public int test 
{ 
    get { return _number; }
    set { _number = value; }
}
```

In the above example, `test` is a public `Property` that accesses a `private` `field`.

Comment: So when I declare `public int test { get; set; }` the field `test` is private with public getters and setters? Same as in Java?
This is what @Simon has said above.

Comment: @rtindru - `test` is a property. Which is public.

Comment: @rtindru - if you did `private int test { get; set; }` then `test` would be a private property.

Comment: @rtindru - I've modified my answer to elaborate slightly more between the fields and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, which is provided by the C# compiler to eaisly create getter and setter method.

```
private int test;

public int Test{
   public get{
      return this.test;
   }
   public set{
      this.test = value;
   }
}
```