# Difference between having no setter and readonly? Is there a difference?

Tags: c#

Came across this,

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

Which I've never really seen before. After investigating, I found a question on [omitted setters vs private setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792392/omitted-setter-vs-private-setter) and it has me thinking it's the property equivalent of `readonly`.

Is this correct? What are the differences?

Comment: Hi when a field is `readonly` it can't be assigned to another value (outside of the declaration or constructor).

Comment: Prior to (IIRC) C#6, you couldn't set a property with an omitted setter even in the constructor. A private setter was the only way to do that in earlier versions of the language.

Comment: Ah, I was focusing my searching around "no setter" instead of just "getter". I figured it had been asked before, I just wasn't finding it.

Comment: It looks like it is calling the setter, but it's not (because it doesn't *have* a setter). It assigns the value directly to the underlying (readonly) variable.